# 50% idle RAM usage which is not freed even when more ram is needed

Tags: windows-10, memory

When I run FarCry 4, ram usage goes over 90% and the game starts using HDD as well. Disk usage goes to 100% and the game lags.

Months ago, this did not happen because idle RAM usage stayed around 25%.

I am attaching screenshots for inspection. Please help me solve this problem. 
Photos show around 80% RAM usage with chrome using around only 800mb.

[image: screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

Comment: Don’t use the Processes tab to check stuff like that. Use the Details tab. Also, you might want to consider upgrading. 4 GB just isn’t enough on Windows. // If you can, provide a save from Sysinternals RamMap. // edit: It appears RamMap is currently broken by Windows 10 updates, so it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

So what did you install/start using between when it worked and now?  Its most likely one of those causing the issue.

In general though to diagnose these types of problems close any other application (include those in the tray) one by one until you find which one caused it.

The likely candidates are AntiVirus/Malware as they activate when other programs run.

Comment: This problem has been a gradual one and not a sudden one. So it is impossible to tell from memory which application's installation is causing this problem. And I have tried running the game with all other applications closed but to no result.

Comment: I am really bothered by the fact that 50% of the Ram is being used and no responsible application can be found  in the task manager.